# RubyMine takes a long time to launch

Tags: rubymine

All of a sudden my RubyMine IDE takes ~1 minute to launch the loading screen.  This started happening right after I installed RubyMine and inserted the license. The IDE itself isn't slow, and file loading loads very fast too. How do I fix this?

Comment: Given you have a purchased license, the best thing to do is to contact JetBrains support and get direct assistance from them.

Comment: Have you changed something in the IDE JVM config? It's an EAP version? Did you tried to close and reopen it and see what happens?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno i didn't change anything. But i did clean my mac using a third party software called CleanMyMac 3 though

Comment: i reinstalled everything, and it's working as fast as it's supposed to be